# Error after get Firebase notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is error, which I get after get Firebase notification:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.readyscript.dk.storemanagement, PID: 7856
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method G()Landroid/content/Intent; in class Lcom/google/firebase/iid/FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdInternalReceiver' appears in /data/data/com.readyscript.dk.storemanagement/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.google.firebase-firebase-iid-9.8.0_8d55835917fc52e46aac681088bc7da722cd628c-classes.dex)
      at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService.zzae(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb.onStartCommand(Unknown Source)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:3297)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap21(ActivityThread.java)
      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565)
      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Before I can get notification from Firebase, but when I add value `data`, my app break after notification. I searched this error, but nothing useful for my situation.

Service:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

public static final String ORDER_ID = "com.readyscript.dk.storemanagement.order_id";
private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMessagingService";

@SuppressLint("LongLogTag")
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Log.d(TAG, "FROM: " + remoteMessage.getData());

    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0){
        Log.d(TAG, "Message data: " + remoteMessage.getData());
    }
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null){
        Log.d(TAG, "Message title: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
        Log.d(TAG, "Message body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());

        String orderId = null;

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : remoteMessage.getData().entrySet()){
            String key = entry.getKey();
            String value = entry.getValue();
            if (key.equals("order_id")){
                orderId = value;
            }
        }

        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle() ,remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody(), orderId);
    }
}

private void sendNotification(String title, String body, String orderId) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, OrderDetailsActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(ORDER_ID, orderId);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri notificationSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ico)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(body)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(notificationSound)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Intent` is an Android method, so your class must extend `Activity`, `Fragment`, or one of their children classes.